# ¿Cómo diseño un algoritmo de BFS que me devuelva el camino?

Tags: c++, c++11

He implementado un algoritmo que mediante BFS me encuentra, en un tablero de 60x60, una posicion que cumple unas ciertas condiciones en concreto y me devuelve una pila con el camino desde una posicion inicial a la posicion deseada o la adyecente a esta segun el caso que me interese estudiar. Ha resultado ser un fracaso puesto que por razones que desconozco siempre me devuelve el camino vacio. ¿Cuál sería un buen ejemplo de algoritmo BFS que devolviera el camino y como se implementaría?

Por si a alguien le sirve, dejo aqui el algoritmo que había diseñado:

En este código tenemos un VVC que sigue es un 
`typedef vector<CellType> VC;
typedef vector<VC> VVC;`y pos inici que es un struct de coordenadas formada por dos enteros. Cuando el camino encuentra una posicion (cell) que es de tipo estación, va añadiendo a una pila path_to_fuel (declarada como atributo `stack<Pos> path_to_enemy;`) el camino que ha ido formando hasta llegar a esa estación. El problema es que nunca me entra en la condicion que hace el push de la respuesta en la pila path_to_fuel, y no se porque dado que el mapa si o si tiene casillas station.

También os dejo la implementación de cell y struct, por si las moscas.

```
enum CellType {
    Desert,Road,City,Water,Station,Wall,
    CellTypeSize
};

struct Pos {
    int i,j;
};

void search(const VVC& mapa, Pos inici) {
    queue<Pos> aux;
    aux.push(inici);
    vector<vector<Pos> >path(60,vector<Pos>(60,Pos(-1,-1)));
    vector<bool> vis (3600,false);
    while (not aux.empty()) {
        Pos act = aux.front();
        aux.pop();
        //cerr << "this cell in position " << act.i << "," << act.j << " has a type of " << cell(act.i,act.j).type << endl;
            if (cell(act).type == Station) {
                int a = path[act.i][act.j].i;
                int b = path[act.i][act.j].j;
                while (path[a][b] != Pos(-1,-1)) {
                    path_to_fuel.push({a,b});
                    int c = a;
                    int d = b;
                    a = path[c][d].i;
                    b = path[c][d].j;
                }
                return;
            }
            if (not vis[act.i*60+act.j]) {
            vis[act.i*60+act.j] = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
                int xx = act.i + pathx[i];
                int yy = act.j + pathy[i];
                if(pos_ok(xx,yy) and not vis[xx*60+yy] and cell(xx,yy).type == Road) {
                        aux.push({xx,yy});
                        path[xx][yy] = {act.i,act.j};
                    }
            }
            }
    }
}
```

---

Creo que es la solución a todos mis problemas pero no acabo de ver exactamente qué hace en este lenguaje. No sé que lenguaje es. Si sirve es un algoritmo recursivo BFS (breadth first search). ¿Alguien podría traducirme este código a c++?

```
dfs BFS(queue=None):
     current_index = queue.get()
     current_x,current_y = current_index[0],current_index_[1]
     element = matrix[current_x,current_y]
     if element == 1: return current_x,current_y
     for n in range(current_x-1,current_x+2):
         for m in range(current_y-1,current_y+2):
         if not (n== current_x and m==current_y) \
            and n>-1 and m>-1 \
            and n<matrix.shape[0] and m<matrix.shape[1] \
            and (n,m) not in queue.queue :
                queue.put((n,m))
    return BFS(queue)
```